# Gerar ID's sequenciais sem perder a sequência

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, hash

Por `Identity` não quero, pois ele quebra a sequência se alguma coisa acontecer. `Max() + 1`, acho muito vulnerável e lento, quando tiver muitos registros. Logo pergunto, há uma forma que alguém conheça, que posso gerar números sequenciais e se houver algum problema na geração, ele não dispara o número, como o identity faz? Dizem que existem algorítmos que fazem isso no Sql Server, mas não gostaria de usar triggers não. Uso `Sql Server 2008`, `Entity 6` e `C#`. Será gerado pelo `C#` com `Entity`.

Comment: usar sequences + transações com isolation level lá em cima (que gera impacto de performance por conta de "enfileiramento") não resolveria pra você?

Comment: O mais comum e indicado é a utilização de [Sequence no SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff878091.aspx), mais se você chamar o Next e não utilizar você perde o numero, para isso acho que você teria que tratar no C#, talvez.

Comment: Sequence só existe a partir do SQL Server 2012, a pergunta é no 2008.

Comment: Por que você precisa de números sequenciais que `identities` não seriam capazes de prover?

Comment: Você está exclusivamente necessitando de uma sequência? Se não, a resposta do @CiganoMorrisonMendex é bastante útil.

Comment: @pnet você está preso ao SQL Server 2008 ou um upgrade é possível?

Answer (score 3):

A melhor maneira de resolver isso é:

Não usando *Identities*.

Para isso você terá que abandonar as chaves sequenciais e partir pra chaves aleatórias. No *Entity Framework*, o tipo de campo é o `Guid`.

A chance de colisão de `Guids` (ou seja, de você gerar dois `Guids` iguais) é de uma em 2.600.000.000.000.000.000.000.

Para usar, declare a chave do seu *Model* da seguinte forma:

```
public Guid MeuModeloId { get; set; }
```

Antes de aplicar `SaveChanges()`, é necessário gerar um `Guid` para a sua propriedade `Id`:

```
meuObjeto.MeuModeloId = Guid.NewGuid();
```

O SQL Server trabalha perfeitamente com `Guids`, mas lá o tipo de dado é chamado de `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (leia mais em http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190348.aspx).

Comment: Acho que isso não atenderia ao requisito de números sequenciais.

Comment: A resposta serve se ele não necessariamente precisar usar uma sequência. Ou então eu posso colocar um algoritmo que respeite uma sequência, mas muito mais complexo.

Answer (score 3):

O recurso que você está procurando existe a partir do `SQL Server 2012` e é chamado `SEQUENCES`.

As `SEQUENCES` são objetos usado para gerar valores de auto numeração, onde podemos definir os valores iniciais e seus incrementos. Eles são objetos independentes das tabelas e triggers e foram criados exatamente para contornar limitações do Identity, como o citado `Max() + 1` por exemplo.

É possível criar uma `SEQUENCE` com o seguinte `T-SQL`

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.NomeSeq AS INT MINVALUE 1 CYCLE;
```

Será criada uma sequencia do tipo `INT` iniciando do número 1, e ao chegar ao limite do tipo (2147483648 no caso de `INT`) do campo, a contagem será reiniciada a partir do `CYCLE`.

Determinar o valor seguinte da sequencia pode ser feito com o comando `NEXT VALUE FOR`

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.NomeSeq;
```

Mais informações referentes a sintaxe e uso do `SEQUENCE` podem ser encontrados [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff878091.aspx).

Comment: Até onde saiba para evitar "banguelas" só com TRANSACTION e ( Max()+1 ou tabela de controle +1) e lock de registro.

Comment: @Motta, tabela de controle, me parece ser o mais óbvio. Ela sempre armazenará o último valor da chave e só gravará um novo valor, após ser gerado a chave e commitado, pois caso haja rollback, ela continuará com o valor anterior(não quebra a sequência). É uma ótima e nem havia pensado nisso.

Comment: @pnet Só tem de tomar cuidado com dead-locks e Sistema travado , a parte de lock e unlock tem de ser a mais rápida possível

Comment: @Motta, valeu pela dica, mas tenho que marcar uma resposta para não deixar o post aberto. Se você sugerir como resposta a tabela de controle, marco a sua. Todas as outras são válidas, mas tenho que escolher uma. Como optei pela tabela de controle, posso marcar a sua caso haja uma resposta.

Comment: Marque a que achar melhor, sem crise.

Answer (score 3):

Simplesmente crie uma tabela paralela de uma linha e um campo só para guardar seu incremento.

Assim, você dá um update nesta tabela com `contador = contador + 1` toda vez que precisar de um novo ID, e o usa na transação seguinte.

O preço é a query extra para obter o ID, mas pode ser mais interessante que o `MAX()+1`, com a vantagem de não voltar o contador caso se delete o registro de número maior. (seria o único caso de "registro banguela", mas é fácil controlar se a tabela auxiliar vai incrementar ou não).

> Esta solução está entre o limiar de uma solução real e um *reparo técnico* <sup>1</sup>, mas funciona bem se for aplicada corretamente.

<sub>1. gambiarra</sub>

> Adendo: se você tiver index na coluna, não muda nada um MAX() com 1 ou com 10000000 registros. Não imagino que qualquer DB razoável iria verificar linha a linha um campo indexado para obter um simples `MAX()`.

Comment: Além disto com TRANSACTION e LOCK dos registros.

Comment: @Motta sim, principalmente para garantir que o ID seja incrementado só se usado com sucesso.

Comment: Então não há resposta para a pergunta do pnet, objetos como Sequences garantem unicidade mas não a integridade, para garantir a unicidade e integridade só garantindo que gravamos o último registro disponível, assim LOCK e TRANSACTION devem ser usados.

Comment: @Motta não pus na resposta pra não complicar, mas sem transaction e lock você ainda pode controlar este processo na aplicação principal. Transaction e lock seriam facilitadores, mas há contornos. Converse com quem já precisou trabalhar com arquivos DBF em pasta compartilhada, que vai encontrar cada solução genial (e outras assustadoras - talvez a grande maioria) pra essas coisas :D

Comment: o que eu vi controlando na Aplicação tem controle do tipo semáforo , em suma sem controle do tipo "garantir a escrita" não garante a integridade.

Answer (score 2):

Criando um sequencial usando uma procedure

```
USE [DBBANCO]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Gerador_Seq]  15:35:53 ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create procedure [dbo].[Gerador_Seq]  @Total int as

DECLARE @intFlag INT

SET @intFlag = 1

WHILE (@intFlag <= @Total )

Begin

    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    INSERT INTO dbo.TEMP_SEQ (my_name) values ('na') ;

    IF @intFlag = @Total
       begin 
         BREAK;
       end
end
  return ''



GO

/** O campo my_id int IDENTITY =>> Completa o Serviço **/
```

Comment: user37310, vou testar isso em casa e posto o resultado. Eu preciso de algo que me gere número sequencial, mas sem quebrar a sequencia em caso de rollback.