# SQL aumentando o ID em 1000 unidades

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma base de dados no SQL Express com uma quantidade razoável de dados já faz mais de um ano. Sempre funcionou tudo bem, mas agora está apresentando o seguinte problema: certas vezes o ID em algumas tabelas acaba aumentando de 1000 unidades.

Pesquisei um pouco sobre isso na internet e vi que isso pode acontecer quando o serviço é reiniciado e nas soluções propostas dizem pra adicionar o parâmetro -t272 na inicialização pelo gerenciador de configurações do SQL. O único problema é que lá no gerenciador a seção  "SQL Server Services" está vazia.

Já resolvi o problema algumas vezes resetando a identidade da tabela pro último valor correto. Isso funciona, mas o problema acaba aparecendo outra vez.

Existe alguma outra solução para esse problema que não seja essa do parâmetro -t272? O que realmente causa isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A partir do SQL Server versão 2012 a *Microsoft* mudou a forma de gerar esses valores, quando a sua instância do SQL Server é reiniciada, então o valor de um campo ***Identity*** pula 1000 se for campo inteiro (int) e 10000 se o campo for do tipo (bigint).

Do nosso ponto de vista da aplicação, este incremento não é aceitável para todos os casos, especialmente quando usamos o valor do Id para exibir ao cliente.

É um caso especial do *SQL Server 2012* e versões mais antigas não têm essa questão.

`Solução 1:`

Abrir o *SQL Server configuration manager*, selecionar a instância do *SQL Server 2012*, clicar com o botão direito em *Properties*/*Startup Parameters*, inserir o valor -t272 e clicar em *Add* e em *Apply*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`Solução 2:`

Remover os campos *Identity* e usar o recurso *Sequence*, onde podemos definir o valor inicial e o seu incremento.

A imagem abaixo mostra onde você pode visualizar as *Sequences* já criadas para o banco de dados e criar uma nova conforme sua necessidade (para maiores detalhes sobre *Sequence* de uma olhada [***aqui***](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3378/utilizando-sequences-no-microsoft-sql-server-2012.aspx)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei uma explicação mais detalhada (em inglês) sobre isso [***aqui***](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-2012-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is) com exemplos.

Comment: +1 para a solução 2, caso esteja utilizando sql server 2012+

Comment: Respondi a um tempo numa pergunta sobre como criar sequences via query. Pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19380/4751

Comment: Note que isto vai ocorrer com TODAS as tabelas que usam auto identity. Portanto a solução 2 pode acabar sendo a mais prática

Comment: O comentário acima falou que o valor de um campo Identity pula 1000 se for campo inteiro (int) e 10000 se o campo for do tipo (bigint), só acontece na SQL Server versão 2012, mais e as versões mais atuais com o 2014,2016 e 2017 isto acontece também com elas?