# Id saltando 1000 Sql server 2014 (localDB)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Na minha aplicação algumas vezes quando vou adicionar algum dado ao banco de dados o ID salta em 1000 unidades.

Achei algumas soluções, mas que para mim não servem pois uso o EF6 com code-first e minha intenção é instalar a aplicação com LocalDB numa maquina sem "componentes de programação".

**O que me ajudaria resolver isso?**

Classe exemplo:

```
 public class ProdutoDTO
    {
        public int produtoID { get; set; }
        public int codigo { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public decimal preco { get; set; }
        public DateTime dataCadastro { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapeamento:

```
class ProdutoConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProdutoDTO>
    {
        public ProdutoConfig()
        {
            HasKey(p => p.produtoID);

            Property(p => p.descricao)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            Property(p => p.preco)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

---

No projeto faço uso de: Code first, EF6, migrations, repositórios genéricos, repositórios de implementação e mapeamento com Fluent Api.

Comment: Como assim está saltando 1000, não seria uma tabela que já foi criada e você está realizando diversas operações sem resetar o identity?

Comment: Tipo, o ultimo Id da tabela produto é 7, dai eu vou adicionar um outro produto e em vez do id ser 8 ele se torna 1008

Comment: sempre o intervalo de 1000? veja como está a configuração de autoincremento da tabela

Comment: Sim, sempre 1000

Comment: Apresente a classe da sua entidade e a configuração de identity da sua tabela

Comment: Edite na pergunta, essa é a sua model da entidade ou apenas uma DTO de fato? Conferiu se o seed não está configurado para 1000?

Comment: Eu separei em 3 camadas e decidir usar DTO, então basicamente essa é minha classe modelo para criação da tabela

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: E o seed do identity?

Comment: Como eu vejo a configuração da seed?

Comment: Execute essa query no banco
`SELECT IDENT_SEED(TABLE_NAME) AS Seed, IDENT_INCR(TABLE_NAME) AS Increment,IDENT_CURRENT(TABLE_NAME) AS Current_Identity
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Produto'`

Comment: Seed : 1 Increment: 1 Current_Identity : 2001

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671899/ids-jumping-up-1000-every-time-i-build-my-app-and-insert-a-new-record

Comment: Possível duplicata de [SQL aumentando o ID em 1000 unidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36881/sql-aumentando-o-id-em-1000-unidades)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo e Márcio respondi um item relacionado a esse aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36881/sql-aumentando-o-id-em-1000-unidades/36890#36890

Comment: @Renan Boa, matou a charada.

Comment: Muito obrigado ao 2, vou ver isso agora, acho que resolve o meu problema

Comment: É um erro do SQL Server, acontece geralmente em caso de falhas no banco de dados.
Tem um parâmetro que deve ser colocado na inicialização do serviço, fazendo assim que o banco crie o log das identidades, evitando a perca da sequencia durante as falhas. verifica nesse link, ele tem o processo completo : http://www.dfarber.com/computer-consulting-blog/2014/2/13/how-to-solve-identity-problem-in-sql-2012/

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36881/sql-aumentando-o-id-em-1000-unidades

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36881/sql-aumentando-o-id-em-1000-unidades