# Gerar Código Unico em Sequencia sem Repetir MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, random

Quero gerar um código de cadastro para cada cliente cadastrado. Como ID eu uso o GUID, porém, ele é para ID(pois é extenso), preciso de um código pequeno, que não seja só um digito, por exemplo: `cód: 0001` , ele não pode se repetir, e eu preciso mostrar ele na tela antes do cadastro. ou seja, quando eu clicar em criar novo cliente, esse código teóricamente é para aparecer um um campo. antes mesmo de persistir no banco. estava lendo a pergunta: **[Como gerar sequências numéricas em SQL sem precisar criar tabelas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19328/gerar-ids-sequenciais-sem-perder-a-sequ%C3%AAncia)**
porém não consegui coopreender.
Perguna 1 : é possivel fazer isso que eu estou propondo? mostrar um código unico, antes de persistir no banco e não repetir esse código?
Pergunta 2 : em caso da pergunta 1 for `true` , e se eu clica em adicionar novo, e depois cancelar, suponto que tenha criado o `cód: 0003`, esse cód ainda ficará disponivel? ou pulará de `0002` para `0004`.
Se alguém conhecer algum material sobre esse assunto, que possa compartilhar comigo, ficaria agradecido.

eu tentei ultilizar o random, porém o radom, não gera sequencia (não que eu tenha conseguido) e ele não faz um consulta no banco para verificar se esse numero gerado da existe(pelo menos eu não sei como fazer).
**Ps: eu estou utilizando MVC 5  e MSSQL SERVER**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme já foi respondido na pergunta mencionada, você pode utilizar o [SEQUENCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) do Sql Server para obter um código sequencial sem repetição.

Você pode criar ele no Sql Server com o seguinte comando:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.NomeSequence
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

Para executar este comando utilizando o EntityFramework Code-First, você precisa criar um arquivo Migration. Para criar o Migration siga os passos abaixo:

Execute este comando no Package Manager Console, na camada da sua aplicação onde esta o Context do EntityFramework:

```
Add-Migration RunSqlScript
```

Ele vai criar uma pasta Migrations, com um arquivo RunSqlScript.cs dentro, este arquivo possui um método up e um down, no método up coloque o script que deseja executar no bd.

```
public partial class RunSqlScript : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.NomeSequence START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Feito isso execute no Package Manager Console o comando

```
Update-Database
```

Com isso no ASP.NET, quando o usuário abrir a tela de novo cadastro, você pode executar no SQLServer o comando [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para já obter o próximo numero sequencial.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.NomeSequence
```

Para pegar o sequense no EntityFramework crie um metodo para executar o select e retornar, este método pode estar no seu Context ou no Repository de algum model.

Exemplo:

```
public int GetNextSequenceValue()
{
    var rawQuery = Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.NomeSequence;");
    var task = rawQuery.SingleAsync();
    int nextVal = task.Result;

    return nextVal;
}
```

Desta forma no momento em que o usuário abre a tela de novo cadastro, você chama o Entity para pegar a sequencia e então pode colocar no campo código da model, e terá um numero sequencial reservado para ele, antes mesmo de inserir os dados do cadastro no bd.

**Conclusão para suas duvidas:**

> Perguna 1 : É possivel fazer isso que eu estou propondo?

Sim, é possível fazer, conforme o exemplo que sitei.

> Pergunta 2: Se eu clica em adicionar novo, e depois cancelar, suponto que tenha criado o cód: 0003, esse cód ainda ficará disponivel? ou pulará de 0002 para 0004.

Como você vai pegar o código antes de persistir, caso o usuário cancele a operação aquela sequencia será pulada, como no exemplo de 0002 para 0004. Isso precisa ser assim pois podem existir múltiplos usuários efetuando cadastros simultaneamente, no que um usuário abre o novo cadastro um código sequencial já tem que ser reservado para ele, para que o próximo usuário pegue um outro código, assim mantendo a integridade da sequencia.

Comment: Cara, desculpa, sou um pouco leigo.. pesquisar como fazer isso, achei essa questão .[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077461/how-to-get-next-value-of-sql-server-sequence-in-entity-framework) . estou usando CodeFirst. como eu mapeio isso para meu cliente? eu tenho uma propriedade no cliente chamada `Codigo`.

Comment: @RafaelPassos não sei exatamente como esta a estrutura do projeto, mas alterei a pergunta com como seria mais ou menos para fazer utilizando o EntityFramework Code-First.

Comment: consegui implementar, mas no hora que chega na parte `int nexVal = task.Result;` da o seguinte erro: `InvalidOperationException: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int64' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.`

Comment: resolvi usando esse script aqui. `SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter("@result", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
   {
      Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
   };

   Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
              "SELECT @result = (NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence)", result);

   return (int)result.Value;`